# Scala for comprehension returns type mismatch; found : Unit

Tags: scala

I would like to understand why this code is not compiling:

```
  def comb(list: List[(Char, Int)]): List[(Char, Int)] = {
    for (tuple <- list) {
      tuple match {
        case p if (p._2 > 1) => List(p) :: List((p._1, p._2 - 1))
        case _               => List(tuple)
      }
    }
  }
```

If I execute this code outside the function and applied directly to a `List` it works. I think my problem is, I don't understand how values are returned.

I got this error from Eclipse:

> type mismatch; found : Unit required: List[(Char, Int)]

I reviewed another answers, mostly with `if` statements, but I still don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `for()` without a `yield` is equivalent to `foreach()`, which returns nothing of interest (a `Unit`), but the definition of `comb()` says that it should return `List[(Char, Int)]`, so the compiler complains.

We can add a `yield` after the `for()` but there's another problem: the code is creating `List` values inside the `for()`, which means that the result will be a `List` of many smaller `List`s. That still doesn't match the method return type.

So we can `.flatten` the internal `List`s to get just one `List` of tuples and this will finally match the return type.

```
def comb(list: List[(Char, Int)]): List[(Char, Int)] = {
  for (tuple <- list) yield {
    tuple match {
      case p if p._2 > 1 => p :: List((p._1, p._2 - 1))
      case _             => List(tuple)
    }
  }
}.flatten

comb(List(('a',9),('b',5),('c',1)))
//res0: List[(Char, Int)] = List((a,9), (a,8), (b,5), (b,4), (c,1))
```

It's worth noting that a `for()` comprehension with only one generator (the `<-` part) is equivalent to a `map()` call. And a `map()` call followed by `.flatten` is equivalent to a `flatMap()` call. So the above is equivalent to:

```
def comb(list: List[(Char, Int)]): List[(Char, Int)] =
  list.flatMap{case (c,i) => (c,i) :: (if (i>1) (c,i-1)::Nil else Nil)}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works and know I learned a bit more. I used a for comprehension just to try different options, and this is just the first part of an exercise, but I got your point.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a yield over there

```
def comb(list: List[(Char, Int)]): List[(Char, Int)] = {
for (tuple <- list) yield {
  tuple match {
    case p if (p._2 > 1) => p :: List((p._1, p._2 - 1))
    case _               => List(tuple)
  }
}
}
```

However this is possibly not the best way to do it in Scala. You could try something like this as an alternative

```
def comb(list: List[(Char, Int)]): List[(Char, Int)] = {
list.map{
 case(char:Char,int:Int) if(int >1)=> (char,int-1)
 case(char:Char,int:Int) => (char,int)
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I really appreciated but I marked the other response as the answer since it also explains why my code it was wrong.